# Where is the icy rock?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I already found the moss rock and evolved eevee to leafeon. I searched all around frost cavern in search of the icy rock. Where is it? :s

Answer (score 7):

Here's a map leading to the Icy Rock in Frost cavern from the first floor up.

At first, there are two stairways, take the right one and you'll end up at the position of the 4th vertical lower green arrow on the right. Find your way to the upper left part of the map (you will need surf) and take the stairway down. That will lead you to the Icy Rock where Eevee will evolve into Glaceon upon level up.

[image]

Comment: ok, i will do that! :)

Comment: @YoshiFan3 I have put a more precise location of the rock in my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: But wait, in what direction and what stream of water?

Comment: @YoshiFan3 Is that so hard? There's only one stream in Frost Cavern. Well, just in case, I added a map of the particular floor. It's the second floor by the way.

Comment: Just being in Frost cavern isn't enough, you need to be on the right floor. I believe it doesn't have to be the exact chamber with the rock, but it has to be the lower level.

Comment: @scenia You need to be in the actual chamber. I just tested to make sure.